# AWK - Counting and printing different patterns

Tags: design-patterns, awk, counting

I have a file with 13 columns. It looks just like this:

```
M01562:52:000000000-A9Y4G:1:1101:10000:13082_1:N:0:1    gene_id_8535    100.00  254 0   0   1   254 302 49  3.2e-140    495.0   254
M01562:52:000000000-A9Y4G:1:1101:10000:18672_1:N:0:1    gene_id_118536  100.00  193 0   0   1   193 54  246 1.6e-103    373.0   193
M01562:52:000000000-A9Y4G:1:1101:10000:18672_2:N:0:1    gene_id_118536  98.83   257 3   0   1   257 427 171 3.4e-137    485.0   257
M01562:52:000000000-A9Y4G:1:1101:10000:21866_2:N:0:1    gene_id_120720  100.00  195 0   0   1   195 448 254 4.9e-104    375.0   200
M01562:52:000000000-A9Y4G:1:1101:10000:5922_1:N:0:1     gene_id_17051   100.00  149 0   0   1   149 1849    1701    3.4e-78 289.0   149
M01562:52:000000000-A9Y4G:1:1101:10000:5922_2:N:0:1     gene_id_17051   100.00  123 0   0   1   123 1522    1644    1.3e-62 237.0   123
M01562:52:000000000-A9Y4G:1:1101:10000:6256_1:N:0:1     gene_id_121202  98.73   157 2   0   1   157 179 23  1.9e-81 300.0   157
M01562:52:000000000-A9Y4G:1:1101:10001:11433_1:N:0:1    gene_id_125209  99.07   108 1   0   1   108 118 11  1.8e-53 207.0   108
M01562:52:000000000-A9Y4G:1:1101:10001:11433_2:N:0:1    gene_id_125209  99.15   118 1   0   4   121 1   118 2.9e-59 226.0   121
M01562:52:000000000-A9Y4G:1:1101:10001:17591_1:N:0:1    gene_id_2387    100.00  152 0   0   1   152 1378    1529    2.2e-80 296.0   152
M01562:52:000000000-A9Y4G:1:1101:10001:17591_2:N:0:1    gene_id_2387    100.00  152 0   0   1   152 1529    1378    2.2e-80 296.0   152
M01562:52:000000000-A9Y4G:1:1101:10001:17844_1:N:0:1    gene_id_9456    100.00  100 0   0   1   100 176 275 8.5e-50 194.0   100
```

Now, what I need to do is count the second column, which are some gene IDs, and print into a separate file that has each gene ID and its number of repetitions or times it appears in the file. Just like this:

```
gene_id_9456           2
gene_id_125209         5
gene_id_2387           2
```

The gene IDs have different number if characters and are different altogether so everything I have tried doesn't work...

Also, could anyone recommend some really good websites to learn about awk? I have been reading http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html but would like to have more sources.

Comment: Don't tell us "something like" your input or best case you'll get "something like" an answer. Telling us a rough format of your data isn't enough. Edit your question to include a small (5-10 lines) set of actual representative sample input and the associated expected output that we could run a script against and compare it's output to if we wanted to test a solution. The best awk resource is the book "Effective Awk Programming", Third Edition by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: @EdMorton: Your information is helpful and your hints are valuable. But the tone is a bit rude and does not really invite first time users to stay. As first question MPR6 did a good job.

Comment: @AxelKemper agreed, my tone was a bit rude but I dont agree the OP did a good job on posting the question. We all know what information we would want to have to help us answer a question. This has nothing to do with posting to this site in particular - just asking people for help with anything in general. So someone posting a question without that information tells me they just cant be bothered putting effort into helping us to help them and they want us to do all of the work for them.

Comment: Sorry about that. I tried to put an example of the data I have but it was all messed up and not very readable. I guess I just need more practice with the formating here. Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: I just edited my post with an example of my data, though the answers the two of you provided have been extremely helpful. Again, thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't see any of the gene ids in your expected output file in what I consider column 2 of your sample input file. Please clarify the mapping between your input and output and/or update your examples so both match if your current sample output is for some reason not based on your sample input. Your example so far has clarified a misunderstanding that both Axel and I had in that we thought you wanted a separate file per gene id so thanks for posting that. If you do not want "Column 1  Column 2" and a blank line at the top of your output file, remove that. Be literal.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. The sample output was not based in the sample input but I have corrected that, and also removed the "Column 1 Column 2". Thanks for all the hints! Next time I'm sure I'll make a better post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are all you need is something like this:

```
awk '{cnt[$2]++} END{for (gene in cnt) print gene, cnt[gene]}' file
```

but without sample input and expected output it's just a guess.

Comment: Pretty compact "code golf" solution! Works like the script suggested in my answer.

Comment: @AxelKemper a "code golf" solution would use single character variable names, this is just a reasonable, concise solution.

Answer (score 1):

The following `awk` script `countGenes.awk` would do the job:

```
#
#  countGenes.awk
#

BEGIN {
    columns = 13
    geneColumn = 2
}

#  select only lines with the expected number of fields    
(NF == columns) {
    geneCounts[$geneColumn]++
}

END {
    #  loop through the associative table of counts
    for (gene in geneCounts) {
        #  write count to file
        fileName = "count_" gene ".txt"
        printf "%s\t%d\n", gene, geneCounts[gene] >fileName

        #  for logging
        printf "%s\t%d\n", gene, geneCounts[gene]
    }
}
```

Run the script with the following command:

```
awk -f countGenes.awk testDataGenes.txt
```